# White line on the right side (on mobile) of the website and link not working

Tags: mobile, hyperlink, responsive, whitespace

I'm new to coding and got stuck with these two problems:

1. White line on the right side of the website when opened on mobile sites
2. Link for LinkedIn on the top left not working

I changed all width to 100vw,a nd I tried replacing the link with an image. Should the  tag be withing the button or the button within the  tag?

Here is my HTML and CSS:
https://github.com/sanja247/portfolio

This is the website: https://sanja247.github.io/portfolio/